# Fastboot not working?

Tags: fastboot, huawei

I have a Huawei Honor 6. I have an unlocked bootloader, and I am trying to install marshmallow. I have flashed TWRP before (and I can boot to it and use it), so fastboot has once worked. Now when I try to do anything. Even to lock the bootloader, it is not possible. If I try to do anything it gives me `Command not allowed error`. Here while flashing:

```
D:\android sdk tools (adb and fastboot)\platform-tools>fastboot flash BOOT "D:\android sdk tools (adb and fastboot)\platform-tools\img\BOOT.img"
target reported max download size of 471859200 bytes
sending 'BOOT' (10272 KB)...
OKAY [  1.084s]
writing 'BOOT'...
FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)
finished. total time: 1.089s
```

I have searched around, but no answers. The phone shows up in fastboot devices. The only command that works correctly is fastboot reboot. fastboot unlock works, but it's already unlocked.

Comment: Have you updated your Android SDK Tools?

Comment: These XDA threads may help Honor6 HONOR MultiTool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2963060) and (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2433454). I own same device and get my answers from XDA or [India specific fb group](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2433454
), needs signing up. Also see [Pantomath](https://m.facebook.com/pantomath.xyz/photos/a.891154317630742.1073741827.887343424678498/959384957474344/?type=3&source=44&refid=17&ref=m_notif&notif_t=group_highlights)

Comment: Android SDK is up to date.

Comment: Also, there are no solutions to the problem on XDA

Comment: I'm going to try and run the unlock command again and see if it fixes it. Wish me luck.

Comment: It says it's already unlocked, and like I said, I cannot relock it, as it gives me Command not allowed error. Help please!